# this.props.x is not a function eventhough x is bound. React.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass the `metricsParams` to be passed from `componentA` to `componentB` when `btn_genReport` is clicked and `generateReport()` is fired. But It throws error as `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.generateReport is not a function`

componentA (metrics-report.jsx)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Input, Collapsible, CollapsibleItem } from 'react-materialize';

class MetricsReport extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        metricsParams: {reportType: ""}
      }
      this.generateReport = this.generateReport.bind(this);
    }
    getReportType(event) {
      console.log(this.state.metricsParams);
      let metricsParams = {...this.state.metricsParams}
      metricsParams.reportType = event.target.value;
      this.setState({metricsParams});

    }

    generateReport() {
      this.props.generateReport(this.state.metricsParams);
    }
    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
      return (
          <div  class="ushubLeftPanel">
              <label>{'Report Type'}</label>
              <select id="metricsDropDown" className="browser-default" onChange={this.getReportType}>
                <option value="MetricsByContent">Metrics By Content</option>
              </select>
              <button id="btn_genReport" onClick={this.generateReport}>Generate Report</button>
          </div>
      )
    }

}

export default MetricsReport;
```

componentB (metrics-report-container.jsx)

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import MetricsReport from '../components/pages/metrics-report';

class MetricsReportContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.generateReport = this.generateReport.bind(this);
    }
    generateReport(metricsParam) {
        console.log('???:', metricsParam);
    }
    componentDidMount() {

    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <MetricsReport generateReport={this.generateReport}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default metricsReportContainer;
```

Comment: The code is ok. The problem cannot be replicated, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xxrwnv

Comment: @estus I guess it works for you because you have done everything from single jsx file

Comment: I don't see how this could affect how this.props.generateReport behaves. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , so it could be replicated by other users.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a typo?

```
export default metricsReportContainer; // it should be MetricsReportContainer
```

In case it's not a typo. I've already checked your codes, I can tell that your codes are totally fine, it works fine.

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/zrm8r6x6m4

I mean, the communication between your parent component and the child component is implemented in the right way, nothing's wrong.

This is the minimal codes that I used to check your implementation.

---

*MetricsReportContainer.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MetricsReport from "./MetricsReport";

class MetricsReportContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.generateReport = this.generateReport.bind(this);
  }
  generateReport(metricsParams) {
    console.log(metricsParams);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MetricsReport generateReport={this.generateReport} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MetricsReportContainer;
```

---

*MetricsReport.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class MetricsReport extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.generateReport = this.generateReport.bind(this);
  }
  generateReport() {
    this.props.generateReport("Hello World!");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.generateReport}>Generate Report</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MetricsReport;
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I was calling child component first instead of parent one.